# Java reflection: Calling methods with different argument dynamically

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to call different methods from a class dynamically.

detFunctions.java:

```
package detFunctions;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.sql.*;  

public class detFunctions{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String funcId = "";
    String funcName = "";
    String funcDesc = "";
    String Input = "";
    try{
        System.out.println("Retrieving Function for Execution....");

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.168.4:2921:SCRDEV","custom","custom");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select FUNC_IDENTIFIER,FUNC_NAME,FUNC_DESC from custom.dfmt");
        Input = "10001|10002|10003";
        while(rs.next()){
            funcId = rs.getString("FUNC_IDENTIFIER");
            funcName = rs.getString("FUNC_NAME");
            funcDesc = rs.getString("FUNC_DESC");       
        }   
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Function execution completed!!!");
    } catch (Exception e){ System.out.println(e);} 
    System.out.println(funcId);
    System.out.println(funcName);
    System.out.println(funcDesc);
    System.out.println(Input);

    //Reflection of DETFunctions (Raw Type)
    String classId = "detFunctions.detFuncSet1";
    Class c = Class.forName(classId);
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(funcId, new Class[] {String.class});
    Object i = c.newInstance();
    Object funcOutput = m.invoke(i, Input);
    System.out.println(funcOutput);


    //Reflection of DETFunctions (Generic Type)

  } //End of Main Function
} //End of class
```

  *

detFuncSet1.java:

```
package detFunctions;

public class detFuncSet1 {

    public double GL_BALANCE(String GLList) {
        System.out.println("GL_BALANCE Method invoked.......");
        double GLBalance = 5005689.50;
        System.out.println("GL_BALANCE Method execution completed.....");
        return GLBalance;
  }

    public double EFF_BALANCE(String AcctNo,String InDate) {
        System.out.println("EFF_BALANCE Method invoked.......");
        double EFFBalance = 500.50;
        System.out.println("EFF_BALANCE Method execution completed.....");
        return EFFBalance;
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to execute methods from detFuncSet1 class using refection. But getDeclaredMethod is a raw type so I am not able to pass the inputs of different types to the methods.

In the above code, getDeclaredMethod has arguments which is parameter type. Based on the query i am executing I am deriving the funcId (which is my method name). Since my methods (in class detFuncSet1 class) are having different inputs I am not able to pass the parametertype dynamically to getDeclaredMethod. Is there a way i can execute my methods dynamically?

Comment: What kind of program is this? You are not following the Java style guide (e.g. lowercase variable names), which is quite confusing. What is the `Input` variable for? It contains a "pipe"-separated string (`|`). Is it supposed to be split?

Comment: That was one input which i have hard coded for the method GL_BALANCE to pass. Sorry for not following the Java style guide.

Comment: The method's name is `EFF_BALANCE` and takes two arguments. I think that's the biggest issue with your program. You need to find out how many arguments to pass for each method. In general, what you are trying to do is also a big security risk.

Comment: Basically that is my requirement, bcoz my application will send me the method name and its input to the table I am selecting. (but here i have hardcoded the input) and going forward i must be able to add more and more methods in defFuncSet1 as the application functionalities enhances.

Answer (score 0):

With reflection, you lose type safety. When calling a method, you just pass an `Object[]` array.